# Update User Meta Via Ajax

Tags: plugins, functions, ajax, users

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I have an ajax function which runs every few seconds and it basically checks 2 database tables and if they do not match then update one of the database tables to match the other database table, but for some reason it doesn't update the database table. How do I edit the function so I can achieve this?

Here is the function:

```
function tb_update_old_followers($user_id) {

    $followers = tb_get_follower_count($user_id);

    $old_followers = tb_get_old_follower_count($user_id);

    $response['new_new_followers'] = $followers;

    $response['old_new_followers'] = $old_followers;

    $response = json_encode( $response );

    echo $response;

    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_tb_old_followed_by_count', $followers + 1);

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_tb_update_old_followers' , 'tb_update_old_followers');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead? Also I see that followers isn't incremented until right at the very end, after the response has already been sent, is that intentional?

Comment: @TomJNowell I got it working and I am still kind of a newbie when it comes to coding so I am not to familiar with REST API, I'm not sure if that requires a dedicated server or something. At the moment I am on a shared hosting server so my options are kind of limited but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Your site already has a REST API, visit `yoursite.com/wp-json`, there's no reason to use admin AJAX in modern WP, especially when REST API endpoints are so easy to add and work with. You're already working with JSON so you're already talking the right language